# Regular expression to test for /CXXX/ needed

Tags: c#, regex

I am just starting to learn about regular expressions. What I need is to check for a slash followed by "C" followed by three uppercase characters / numbers and then another slash followed by anything.

```
var a = "/C001/dsafalkdsfjsadfj";
var b = "/CXXX/adsf";
```

Can someone tell me how I can do a check for this within an if test?

if ( regular expression ) {}

Comment: Did you even read any documentation? This kind of thing is usually explained in the first few pages of any regex tutorial. Sorry for complaining but I'm getting bored of seeing so many elementary regex questions (or rather, requests for instant solution).

Comment: What I am not sure of is if there's another way to do it that is simpler than setting up a new regular expression and then doing a count. In C# is there some kind of quick and easy one time test like: if ( a == "abc" ) ?  but something else rather than "abc" that would be like a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

try that :

you wrote :

*and then another slash followed by anything*

which is not your example  , but anyway :   (according to the **sentence** )

```
 \/C[A-Z0-9]{3}\/$
```

(according to the **example** : )

```
 \/C[A-Z0-9]{3}\/[a-z]$
```

(according to your response : )

```
 \/C[A-Z0-9]{3}\/


Regex regex = new Regex (@"\/C[A-Z0-9]{3}\/$");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(yourstring);
if matches.Count>0...
```

Comment: Would use \/C([A-Z0-9]{3})\/.*$ as the regex.

Comment: Sorry. What I meant to say was that I only care that it starts with a slash, has a C, then 3 aphanumeric and then another slash. There will be something after the second slash but it could be any combination of characters. I don't really care what's after the second slash. Thanks.

Comment: @Royi I added a verbatim string literal to make it compile; note the `\/` is not strictly necessary AFAIK - could be just `/` - but works either way

Comment: @SamanthaJ so just take away the trailing `$` - i.e. `"/C[A-Z0-9]{3}/"`

Comment: Is there some way I can combine this into a one line if statement test? I can't remember what language but before I used to do this with just a single line. Maybe is there some way other than using Regex ?

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "/C001/dsafalkdsfjsadfj";
var pattern = @"/C[A-Z0-9]{3}/.*";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
string result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
    result += "match " + i + ",value:" + matches[i].Value + "\n";
}
Console.WriteLine("Result:\n"+result);
```